# Number of days of current week within a given date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In an xls project tracking sheet I have the following columns:
1. Proj name
2. Resource name
3. hrs per day
4. From date
5. to date

[image]

there are multiple resources working on multiple projects. I want to:

1. for a given resource in each row check if their "From date" and "To date" columns fall under the current week dates (Mon-Fri).
2. Count those number of days.
3. Pick the "hrs per day" and multiply with num of days (from 2. above) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula (it is a little convoluted but it works):

```
=D2*(IF(IF(OR($C$9>F2,$C$10<E2),0,1)=1,MIN(F2,$C$10),0)-IF(IF(OR($C$9>F2,$C$10<E2),0,1)=1,MAX(E2,$C$9),0))
```

Here is an example of how it works calculating the number for each row. After that you can summarize anyway you want.

[image]

Comment: Hi - Thank you. However, what are the StartDate and EndDate values for? the formula should consider columns E and F as the start and end dates and within that range should count the number of week working days ?

Comment: Hi - I think you are providing a week range in C9 and C10 which is then used by the formula? If so, can this input be a single date. for ex: if we provide input date as 8/06/2019 the system should provide num of working days in col G within that week for respective date ranges of each resource. So Resource 1 in your example will show 5x4 = 20 hrs in col G.

Comment: If you for example have the date in c12, you could calculate the start date as C12-WEEKDAY(C12)+2 and the end date as C12-WEEKDAY(C12)+6, by combining the 3 formulas it would be at the end: =D2*(IF(IF(OR(($C$12-WEEKDAY(C12)+2)>F2,($C$12-WEEKDAY(C12)+6)<E2),0,1)=1,MIN(F2,($C$12-WEEKDAY(C12)+6)),0)-IF(IF(OR(($C$12-WEEKDAY(C12)+2)>F2,($C$12-WEEKDAY(C12)+6)<E2),0,1)=1,MAX(E2,($C$12-WEEKDAY(C12)+2)),0))

Comment: Hi - Is there a way I can upload my excel here. I am having a glitch with the formula where it is adding an extra hrs/day unit.

Comment: You could add a screenshot of the excel (clearly showing the column headers and row numbers) plus the formula

Comment: hi - I am unable to see the option to add the screen shot / upload a image either.

Comment: hi I did find a problem with the formula but it was actually considering one day less, so the formula on G2 should be (and the date in C2): `=D2*(IF(IF(OR(($C$12-WEEKDAY($C$12)+2)>F2,($C$12-WEEKDAY($C$12)+6)<E2),0,1)=1,MIN(F2,($C$12-WEEKDAY($C$12)+6))+1,0)-IF(IF(OR(($C$12-WEEKDAY($C$12)+2)>F2,($C$12-WEEKDAY($C$12)+6)<E2),0,1)=1,MAX(E2,($C$12-WEEKDAY($C$12)+2)),0))`

Answer (score 1):

In a new column use the "=NETWORKDAYS([startdate],[enddate))" to calculate number of M-F. You can also include holidays in the formula. From there you can multiple the hours by the days.

Please be kind and leave feedback! Cheers!

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your response. NETWORKDAYS only gives number of working days between a date range. However, what I am looking for is how many days of the current week are in a given date range. for ex current week is Jul 29 - Aug 2. So, based on my sample table above, the formula should provide list as follows: 

Resource 1 = 20hrs  (i.e 4 hrs x 5 days)
Resource 3 = 20 hrs (i.e 4 hrs x 5 days)
:
Resource 6 = 0 hrs  (ex his date range does not fall in current week)
Resource 10= 3 hrs  (ex his To/From dates are 29-Jul to 31-Aug and working 1 hr a day)
etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a few helper columns as below:

**Curr_Mon** being the Monday's date of current week. In my solution it is 5/8/2019

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1
```

**Curr_Fri** being the Friday's date of current week. In my solution it is 9/8/2019

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+5
```

**From_Check** being the bigger one between **From** date and **Current Monday**

```
=MAX(E2,G2)
```

**To_Check** being the smaller one between **To** date and **Current Friday**

```
=MIN(F2,H2)
```

**Total Days** being the difference between **To_Check** date and **From_Check** date, **if negative use 0**

```
=MAX(0,J2-I2+1)
```

**Total Hours** is the **Hrs/Day** multiply by **Total Days**

```
=D2*K2
```

See below screenshot for clarifications:
[image: Solution]

I have added a couple sample data (highlighted in yellow) to test the result.

Let me know if you have any question.

Cheers :)

Comment: Hi Terry - Thank you. I will put this in my excel and try out and let you know the outcome.